# Can not log into sandbox by test account on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am implementing in app purchases for my app. I am logged out from AppStore, created some test accounts, have not verify it by e-mail.
And every time I tried to log in into sandbox app-purchase I got an transaction error. Btw product info restored correctly.
Looking deeply I notice that after any attempt to log in, my AppStore account setting in device filled with the info from this test account! So I think it tries to log in into real AppStore instead of sandbox.

What am I doing wrong? Why my test accounts tries to login into the real AppStore and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know if you're in sandbox environment or not, you can have a look at the purchase popup. If you can read "[Sandbox environment]" at the bottom, then it means you're using the sandbox. Otherwise, you're using the real Appstore (But I'm pretty sure it's not the case since this is automatically chosen by the device).

Anyway, it seems that Apple Sansbox environment is experiencing some problems today.
For example, I have an app that was dealing correctly with inapp purchase yesterday. Today, only retrieving SKProducts was ok.

I recommend you to be patient until the problem is fixed by Apple.

Comment: [Sandbox] label appears with the payment information when I initiated purchase. After I pressed Ok the login window appears. This login window doesn't have any 'sandbox' labels on it.

Comment: It seems that the sandbox server is now working. You can continue working ;)